# How to Automatically send a password reset email with firebase auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

What I have is a signin page where people can sign in with Firebase Auth but I have't made a can't login component where if they forget there password a password reset occurs with the new password emailed to the user.

I have read the documentation about this at Generate password reset email link in the Generating Email Action Links section of the firebase documentation under authentification and it shows me this code for node.js.

```
// Admin SDK API to generate the password reset link.
const userEmail = 'user@example.com';
getAuth()
  .generatePasswordResetLink(userEmail, actionCodeSettings)
  .then((link) => {
    // Construct password reset email template, embed the link and send
    // using custom SMTP server.
    return sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(userEmail, displayName, link);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Some error occurred.
  });
```

I have also seen the docs on Create custom email action handlers and seen this

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // TODO: Implement getParameterByName()

  // Get the action to complete.
  const mode = getParameterByName('mode');
  // Get the one-time code from the query parameter.
  const actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode');
  // (Optional) Get the continue URL from the query parameter if available.
  const continueUrl = getParameterByName('continueUrl');
  // (Optional) Get the language code if available.
  const lang = getParameterByName('lang') || 'en';

  // Configure the Firebase SDK.
  // This is the minimum configuration required for the API to be used.
  const config = {
    'apiKey': "YOU_API_KEY" // Copy this key from the web initialization
                            // snippet found in the Firebase console.
  };
  const app = initializeApp(config);
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  // Handle the user management action.
  switch (mode) {
    case 'resetPassword':
      // Display reset password handler and UI.
      handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang);
      break;
    case 'recoverEmail':
      // Display email recovery handler and UI.
      handleRecoverEmail(auth, actionCode, lang);
      break;
    case 'verifyEmail':
      // Display email verification handler and UI.
      handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang);
      break;
    default:
      // Error: invalid mode.
  }
}, false);
```

I know this is probably an easy problem but I'm very new to this and I've been unable to find any good tutorial videos on this and I was hoping someone here might be able to show me an example of how to do it or a link to somewhere that explains it so that even I can understand, any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet in your question ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link)) is Admin SDK code and, as such, needs to be executed from "privileged environments" as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

With “privileged environment” the documentation means a **server that you fully control** or **a Cloud Function in your Firebase Project** that runs back-end code (and that you also control, since it is in your own Project). So this code should not be executed in your front-end app.

The easiest way is to use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that you can trigger by different means, depending on your functional needs, e.g. by [calling it from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd), by [creating a Firestore document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd), etc...

As documented in the code snippet

```
// Construct password reset email template, embed the link and send
// using custom SMTP server.
return sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(userEmail, displayName, link);
```

you need to send yourself the email, including generating the email content (by including the link returned by the `generatePasswordResetLink()` method) and send it, by using your own SMTP server or a service like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/). The `sendCustomPasswordResetEmail()` function in this snippet is just a "fake" function that illustrates the fact that you need to implement the actions described in my previous sentence.

---

Then, the second code snippet in your question is to be executed in the user's browser. Upon email reception the user clicks on the link and you should present the user a web page that implements the code in the `handleResetPassword()` function detailed  in the [documentation where you got this second code snippet](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) (see section/bullet point #2).

Note that the second code snippet deals with all the different email action handlers, i.e. resetting passwords but also revoking email address changes or verifying email addresses. In your case you just need to implement the code in the `handleResetPassword()` function.

Comment: Hey @Epimetheus14, did you have time to look at the proposed answer?